# How to refactor out react-hook warning when a ref is in the dependency list for useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a useEffect callback in my functional component whose responsibility is to determine whether the content of a child overflows its container, and if so, to show a "More" link that will allow the container to be expanded.

```js
  const cardNode = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOverflown(cardNode.current)) {
      setShowExpander(true);
    } else {
      setShowExpander(false);
    }

    function isOverflown(element) {
      if (element) {
        return (
          element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight ||
          element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth
        );
      }

      return false;
    }
  }, [cardNode.current]);
```

Not wanting this effect to run at every render, I have put a reference to the DOM node in the list of dependencies, or rather the ref's `current` member.

I am getting this `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning:

```
react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'cardNode.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'cardNode.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating the
m doesn't re-render the component.
```

Is my use case a legitimate exception where I shouldn't care about this warning? Is there a better approach to achieve the same objective?

**Updated**

The reason I cannot leave the dependency list out is that it seems the node's scrollHeight and clientHeight values are updated at some point after mounting. Initially, by logging to the console, I can see that the scrollHeight and clientHeight are identical, even though all the content that overflows the parent container is already there.

Thus, I need the side effect to run again, once the scrollHeight and clientHeight "stabilizes" on its final values in order to set the state of whether I want an expander to show up or not can be accurately determined.

Comment: you can try useLayoutEffect without any dependency

Comment: @a-c-sreedhar-reddy Thanks for the suggestion. I had to re-read the documentation on this because I haven't used useLayoutEffect in a long time, if at all. Unfortunately, that doesn't improve the situation.